# How to say "electricity is on" in English?

Tags: phrase-request

How to say "electricity is on" in English? For example, if there's a blackout, and I'm telling a person that we'll talk when the power is on; mind you, I'm not telling that person that we'll talk when the power is back on, but when the power is active/there. How would I say that?

Let's take another example. Suppose my friend lives in an area where power outages/load shedding is common. I want to inquire whether the power is active/on right now in their area or is it cut off. How would I say that? Is the power ____ in your area right now? –

Comment: You already have: *the power / electicity is (back) on*. It doesn't make any sense to distinguish between power being *back on* versus *active*, unless you want to say that there is a *live current* (as in, don't touch the electrical wire).

Comment: "The power is back on" means that an AC voltage potential has reappeared at all wall sockets. It's coincident with any plugged-in device starting to work again, but it doesn't require it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when the power is on" but not "when the power is back on"  I don't understand this question.

Comment: @JamesK Yeah I understand I wasn't very clear. Let's take another example. Suppose my friend lives in an area where power outages/load shedding is common. I want to inquire whether the power is active/on right now in their area or is it cut off. How would I say that? Is the power ____ in your area right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual expression is "the power is on", or in case of a blackout or powercut, "the power is off". So, talking on the telephone:

> Is the power off in your area right now?
>
> Yes
>
> We'll talk when the power is back on. (implictly "in your area")

You can equally ask "is the power on?"  It is implicitly about "in your area" when you are talking to someone on the phone.